# Reset a 2nd-hand iPad that has "Find my iPhone" activated

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone

My iPad died to the point it wouldn't even boot up. So I sold it as-is for parts on eBay. Since it wouldn't boot I could not erase it before selling it.

I've now been contacted by the buyer (in Russia) who says they have gotten the iPad working but because of "Find my iPhone" being active they can't reset it.

Obviously I don't want to give the buyer my iCloud password. Is it possible for me to allow the buyer to reset the iPad by removing it from "Find my iPhone", or remotely erasing it, or some other method? How can I indicate to Apple that I'm happy for anyone to reset this device?

Comment: You can log into iCloud.com in a normal browser on a computer.  Click find my iPhone icon to bring up your devices, find that one and remove it from your account.  That is all that needs to bed done.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365

Comment: I wasn't sure that removing the iPad from my account would allow the new owner to reset it. But you are correct, going through the remove process states exactly that. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!